# How to deserialize ReadOnlySpan<char> to object using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json-deserialization, system.text.json

I have a case when I get a very big text data & each line contains some metadata + json data string.
I need to process the json data on each line.

This is what I have:

```
public Data GetData(string textLine)
{
    var spanOfLine = textLine.AsSpan();
    var indexOfComma = spanOfLine.IndexOf(":");
    var dataJsonStringAsSpan = spanOfLine.Slice(indexOfComma + 1);

    // now use dataJsonStringAsSpan which is ReadOnlySpan<char> to deserialize the Data
}
```

Where Data is a Dto class which has bunch of (7) different attributes:

```
public class Data
{
    public int Attribute1 { get; set; }

    public double Attribute2 { get; set; }
    // ... more properties, emitted for the sake of brevity
}
```

I'm trying to achieve this with `System.Text.Json` API. Surprisingly it doesn't have any overload to deserialize from `ReadOnlySpan<char>`, so I come up with this:

```
public Data GetData(string textLine)
{
    var spanOfLine = textLine.AsSpan();
    var indexOfComma = spanOfLine.IndexOf(":");
    var dataJsonStringAsSpan = spanOfLine.Slice(indexOfComma + 1);

    var byteCount = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(dataJsonStringAsSpan);
    Span<byte> buffer = stackalloc byte[byteCount];
    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataJsonStringAsSpan, buffer);
    var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Data>(buffer);
    return data;
}
```

While this works, it looks very convoluted.

Is this the way to go or am I missing something more simple ?

Comment: is there a particular reason you need to convert each line of text to a span..? Strings are much easier to work with and work natively with the json api, and if you're already given a string, why not just take the substring containing the json data?

Comment: If your text is “very big” and you don’t want to create a String object for it, you -definitely- don’t want to stackalloc. You could deserialize `dataJsonStringAsSpan.ToString()` (ToString on `ReadOnlySpan<char>` is “copy these contents to a string”, not “be a debugging aid/display value”)

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to share a (simplified) example of the JSON you are trying to deserialize?  Also, if your JSON is *very big* then you don't want to load it into a single `string` to begin with, it will go on the large object heap and possibly obviate any advantages you get from using `System.Text.Json`.  (Maybe I'm misunderstanding though and each `textLine` is not very big?)  Are you reading the JSON from a local file, from a HTTP response, or something else?

Comment: If you absolutely need to minimize memory pressure, you can see how Microsoft implements `Deserialize(string json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options = null)` [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/784cb6b5b7e947d3a69c7183847652a0e9335ff0/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializer.Read.String.cs#L52).

Comment: It looks as though you could create your own version of that code with additional arguments `int start, int length`, and pass those to [`AsSpan(string, int, int)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.asspan?view=netcore-3.0#System_MemoryExtensions_AsSpan_System_String_System_Int32_System_Int32_).  You'd also need your own version of a couple methods from [`JsonReaderHelper`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/784cb6b5b7e947d3a69c7183847652a0e9335ff0/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Reader/JsonReaderHelper.Unescaping.cs#L244).  Not sure it's worth it.

Comment: Thank you all for suggestions, and I'm really sorry for late response. I'm trying to avoid working with strings to reduce allocation because as I stated in my question text files are very big (few Gb). Once span sliced, I don't want to have json span converted to string, because I'm going back to string allocations which I was trying to avoid at first place. @dbc you're correct assuming json portion is not big (it's just 7 attribute data). Those text files are downloaded from Azure Blob storage.

Comment: I'll look into referenced MS implementation and try to use benchmarks to find the most optimal solution.

Answer (score 3):

**.Net6** support `Deserialize(ReadOnlySpan<Char>`, [show ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-jsonserializer-deserialize(system-readonlyspan((system-char))-system-type-system-text-json-serialization-jsonserializercontext))

## Example

```cs
  ReadOnlySpan<char> jsonString = "....";

  WeatherForecast? weatherForecast = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WeatherForecast>(jsonString);
```

Online [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qdo3kA)

Answer (score -2):

Will this work the same?  Just reading your code, it looks like it will do the same thing...

```
public Data GetData(string textLine)
{
    var split = textLine.Split(new char[] {':'});
    var data = JsonSerializer.DeserializeObject<Data>(split[1]);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Good catches, @Klaycon

Comment: Sorry for late response. This will do the job, however this is exactly what I was trying to avoid at first place. That `textLine.Split(new char[] {':'});` there is going to allocate an array for each line (and another one because you have `new char[] {':'}` and there are many many lines to be processed).

Comment: @Mike That is true, but they are both local variables and should be GC'd rather quickly.  The memory usage should be pretty slight the whole time. I'd give it a try but I'm betting you won't have any severe memory issues.

Comment: You are allocating two more strings. If you use span, you don't need to allocate.